# Elasticbeanstalk nginx extension for client_max_body_size not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For an application I deploy on beanstalk, getting the error `client intended to send too large body: 1505618 bytes`

Platform: `Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.20`

Added `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` containing `client_max_body_size 64M;` to root.

Added

```
<resource>
  <directory>.platform</directory>
  <targetPath>.platform</targetPath>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

to `pom.xml`

Not sure why the extension isn't taking effect, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.20` **uses Amazon Linux 1** (AL1), not AL2. `.platform` is only supported in AL2. How to configure nginx on AL1, is described in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html) and must be done using `.ebextensions` (not `.platform`).

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Updated to `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` and replaced `.platform` with `.ebextensions` in pom.xml, still getting the error unfortunately

Comment: I do see the following in eb-cfn-init.log :
```Running 1 of 7 actions: HealthdLogRotation...
Running 2 of 7 actions: HealthdHTTPDLogging...
Running 3 of 7 actions: HealthdNginxLogging...
Running 4 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
Running 5 of 7 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
Running 6 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild...
Running 7 of 7 actions: InfraCleanEbextension...```

Comment: Not sure if my addition to `pom.xml` is correct and/or necessary. Other note, unsure if relevant, just uploading the JAR file to beanstalk.

Comment: @JCrea You have to check AWS documentation that I linked how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it to resolve with the above (.ebextensions, pom.xml edit) + zipped the JAR file with the .ebextensions folder and uploaded that to beanstalk